# Encrypt on jenkins or S3 and decrypt on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to automate the deployment of new code on my application using AWS CodeDeploy. I'm using AWS to run my application. What I want to do is the following:

1. Build the application in jenkins (runs on AWS as well)
2. Send the compiled application on S3, along with some environment variables that are to be set automatically by CodeDeploy hooks (AfterInstall)
3. CodeDeploy will take care of the rest of the steps

What I want to know is, is there a AWS practice to encrypt those env vars (they are in a text file) while on S3 and decrypt them when inside the instance? If not, do you have any pointers on how I could achieve what I want (some security regarding these env vars while on S3)?

P.S. The reason for uploading these env vars in S3 and setting on every deployment is because they tend to change. I don't want to bake them in the image. Moreover moving away from env vars is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When putting data in Amazon S3, there are two ways to encrypt the data:

1. Client-side encryption, or
2. Server-side encryption.

#### Client-side Encryption

Amazon does not have any built-in client-side encryption mechanism. You'll have to roll this yourself: Encrypt the data in Jenkins using your favourite tool then upload it. When the objects are downloaded from S3, decrypt the objects after they are downloaded.

One way you could do this is using `7z` to zip and encrypt the archive using AES256 encryption. Another is using OpenSSL.

#### Server-side Encryption

Amazon does have a built-in server-side encryption mechanism.

If you are using the AWS CLI to upload your files to S3, you can use the `--server-side-encryption` command-line argument to have your files encrypted on the server. When the objects are downloaded, they will automatically decrypted.

However, be aware, that this does not protect the object against being downloaded via the S3 API from anyone but you. If anyone uses valid AWS credentials and downloads the file, it will be open to them.

What it does protect against is someone accessing the object via non-API means, such as direct data-center access.

#### Final Notes

If you want the files to be unreadable to anyone but you, ever, then you want client-side encryption.

Comment: This `When the objects are downloaded, they will automatically decrypted.` is what I was missing. Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Have a great day

Comment: S3-tools has a client-side encryption mechanism: http://s3tools.org/kb/showall3.htm#9